# xmlpullparser (bad file descriptor)

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

I'm fairly new to android and I'm trying to parse some xml using XmlPullParser but I keep getting this error (the point at which it happens is fairly inconsistent, sometimes it gets further before it errors)

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: com.example.android.unescotracker, PID: 21828
              java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
```

I'm calling this code on button press that then runs my code as an AsyncTask:

```
public class DatabaseManager{
private static String LOG_TAG = DatabaseManager.class.getName();

private static String XMLSTREAM = "http://whc.unesco.org/en/list/xml/";

public static void runDatabaseManager(Boolean isConnected){
    if (isConnected) {
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                URL url = XmlUtils.createUrl(XMLSTREAM);
                InputStream stream = null;

                try {
                    stream = XmlUtils.makeHttpRequest(url);
                } catch (IOException e){
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IOException Error: Trying to get URL stream", e);
                }

                updateDatabase(stream);
            }
        });
    }

}

private static void updateDatabase(InputStream stream){
    try {
        XmlUtils.getSitesFromXml(stream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IOException Error: Trying to close xml stream", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

actual xml parser class

```
public class XmlUtils {
private static String LOG_TAG = XmlUtils.class.getName();

public static void getSitesFromXml (InputStream stream) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException{
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();

    parser.setInput(stream, null);

    int event = parser.getEventType();
    Log.d("XML", "Starting to read doc");
    while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            String name = parser.getName();

            if (name.equals("row")) {
                readSite(parser);
            }
        }
        event = parser.next();
    }
    Log.d("XML", "Finished Reading");
}

private static void readSite(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    String siteName = "";
    String tag = "";
    int event;
    Log.d("XML", "reading new row");

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "row");
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        event = parser.getEventType();
        if (event == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            if (parser.getName().equals("row")) {
                break;
            }
            continue;
        } else if (event != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }

        tag = parser.getName();
        Log.d("XML", tag);

        switch (tag) {
            case "site":
                siteName = readText(parser);
                Log.d("XML", siteName);
                break;
        }
        Log.d("XML", Integer.toString(parser.next()));
    }
}

// For the tags title and summary, extracts their text values.
private static String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    String result = "";
    if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        result = parser.getText();
        parser.nextTag();
    }
    return result;
}

// Make HTTP GET request for JSON data
public static InputStream makeHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    // Catch null url and return
    if (url==null){
        return inputStream;
    }

    try{
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(20000); // Milliseconds
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(25000); // Milliseconds
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();
        int response = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        }else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "HTTP Request Failed, Response Code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IOException Error: Problem getting JSON data", e);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null){
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    return inputStream;
}

// Return URL object from String URL
public static URL createUrl(String stringUrl){
    URL url = null;

    try {
        url = new URL(stringUrl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e){
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Malformed URL Error: Trying to create URL", e);
    }

    return url;
}

}
```

The biggest thing that confuses me is that it's inconsistent about where it fails while parsing the xml. Just moving the logs around will make it error at different points, does that mean it's something to do with the asynctask or a memory issue?